# Python - variable scope and modification

Tags: python, python-2.7, scope

I'm writing a Python script that is mostly a GUI framework for live forensic data collection on a Windows host. Up until now, I haven't had many problems that I couldn't work through. But this one has me stumped. It likely is a problem involving improper variable scope, but for the life of me, I can't find the problem. The script itself is over two thousand lines long, so I'll copy the relevant portions unless otherwise instructed.

I made a change to my code somewhere along the line that broke the functionality. It used to work perfectly as intended, and now I can't figure out why it doesn't. This will definitely lead me to use versioning software for projects in the future, that's for sure.

What's odd is that there are no exceptions thrown at all.

What I'm trying to do is have the user select Tkinter Checkbutton widgets corresponding to an optional function they want to perform. I have set up Tkinter IntVars for each Checkbutton widget, and placed these IntVars into an array for easy enumeration. The GUI has a "Start" button, which when pressed, initiates the start() function. This function should enumerate the Checkbutton IntVars in the array and perform relevant functions if the IntVar is set to 1 (indicating selection).

All the other parts of my code function as intended. I am having a horrible time with populating the arrays. It seems I cannot modify the arrays, even if declared global within functions. If I set the values in the array manually, it functions as intended. I cannot iterate through the IntVars and set the "global" arrays to what should be their correct values. It seems the two arrays never get modified, acting as if none of the Checkbutton IntVars are set to '1' by being selected.

```
#this is an array of integers corresponding to the checked
#state of desired filetypes for collection
filetypes = [0]*34

#this is an array of integers corresponding to optional collection items
optionalitems = [0]*10

#... snipped ...

#This function performs just fine if the filetypes array is set manually...
#extensions[] is an array containing file extension strings corresponding
# to the Checkbuttons on the fileSelector Toplevel widget.
#outputdirs[] is an array containing strings with a desired output directory.
def collectFiles():
    global filetypes

    n = 0
    print("Parsing checkboxes for file collection...\r\n")
    for item in filetypes:
        if item:
           print(extensions[n] + " selected...")
           #make output dir corresponding to the desired extension
           outputdest = cwd + "/output/" + computername + outputdirs[n]
           if not os.path.exists(outputdest):
               print(outputdest + " does not exist, creating...")
               os.makedirs(outputdest)
               print("Collection for " + outputdirs[n] + " beginning...")
               for drive in drives:
                   print("Searching drive " + drive + "...")
                   for filename in search(drive, extensions[n]):
                       try:
                           i = 2
                           #outpath = cwd + "/output/" + username + outputdirs[n]
                           tempbasename = os.path.basename(filename)
                           testpath = os.path.join(outputdest, tempbasename)
                           tempbasename2 = ""
                           while os.path.exists(testpath):
                               print(testpath + " exists in output directory.")
                               tempbasename2 = str(i) + "_" + tempbasename
                               i += 1
                               testpath = os.path.join(outputdest, tempbasename2)
                           shutil.copy2(filename,testpath)
                           print("Copied:\n\t" + filename + "\n to:\n\t" + testpath + "\n")
                           logfile.write(str(datetime.datetime.now()) + "- Copied:\r\n\t" + filename
                                     + "\r\n to:\r\n\t" + testpath + "\r\n\r\n")
                       except:
                           print("****Problem copying: " + filename + "\n")
                           logfile.write(str(datetime.datetime.now()) + "****Problem copying: " + filename
                                     + "\r\n\r\n")
                           pass
        n += 1

#... snipped ...

#here's where the oddness begins.
#The optionalitems array SHOULD be set outside of this
# function, before it is called.
def doOptionalCollection():
    x = 0
    for item in optionalitems:
        if item:
            optionfunctions[x]()
        x = x + 1

    collectFiles()

#this is the routine called when the "Start" button is pressed.
# The goal here is to enumerate the checkboxes on the GUI, and
# fill filetypes[] and optionalitems[] with values corresponding to
# whether or not the Checkbuttons are selected.
def start():
    global filetypes
    global optionalitems

    #... snipped ...
    #code here performs baseline forensic data collection,
    # and performs exactly as intended.
    #... snipped ...

    #get status of checkboxes and update optionalitems array.
    # optionArray is the Array of IntVars associated with Tkinter Checkbuttons
    # obj.get() --> 0 = unchecked, 1 = checked
    i = 0
    for obj in optionArray:
        optionalitems[i] = obj.get()
        i = i + 1

    doOptionalCollection()

#this is for a dialog-style window that pops up when a button is pressed.
# The dialog contains 34 checkboxes, each with a variable to hold the state.
def showFileSelector():
    global filetypes
    fs = Toplevel(master=root)
    fs.title("Collect files by extension...")
    #set up a grid based on the extensions dictionary keys.
    # have the grid wrap on the 6th element.

    #... snipped, setup of Checkbutton tkinter windgets ...

    buttonArray = [txtButton, pdfButton, logButton, docButton, docxButton,
               rarButton, zipButton, isoButton, jarButton, jpgButton,
               jpegButton, bmpButton, pngButton, gifButton, exeButton,
               pptButton, pptxButton, aviButton, mp4Button, movButton,
               flvButton, mpgButton, wmvButton, mp3Button, flacButton,
               wmaButton, m4aButton, wavButton, psdButton, rawButton,
               apkButton, szipButton, indexdatButton, thumbsdbButton]

    #using filetypes array, set the status of the checkbox.
    #this is helpful if the dialog is re-opened, it will
    # re-populate the dialog with previous selections.
    x = 0
    for item in buttonArray:
        if filetypes[x]:
            item.select()
        x = x + 1

    varArray = [txtvar, pdfvar, logvar, docvar, docxvar,
            rarvar, zipvar, isovar, jarvar, jpgvar,
            jpegvar, bmpvar, pngvar, gifvar, exevar,
            pptvar, pptxvar, avivar, mp4var, movvar,
            flvvar, mpgvar, wmvvar, mp3var, flacvar,
            wmavar, m4avar, wavvar, psdvar, rawvar,
            apkvar, szipvar, indexdatvar, thumbsdbvar]

    def accept():
        global filetypes
        #user has possibly chosen files to collect by extension.
        # iterate varArray to determine what files to collect,
        # and store the result in filetypes[].
        #This assignment also does not work.
        x = 0
        for var in varArray:
            #var.get() to get the values of checkboxes
            # 0 = unchecked
            # 1 = checked
            filetypes[x] = var.get()
            x = x + 1
        fs.destroy()


    def cancel():
        #user has decided to discard selections and close
        # the window.
        fs.destroy()

    #... snipped, GUI placement ...

#back to the base-level indentation (no indents... not inside any functions)

#... snipped, optional item GUI Checkbutton setup ....

optionArray = [productkeyvar, outlookvar,
               recyclebinvar, skypevar,
               prefetchvar, installlogvar,
               allmediavar, win7jumplistvar,
               win7thumbcachevar, recentfilesvar]

optionfunctions = [collectProductKeys, collectOutlookAttachments,
                   collectRecycleBin, collectSkypeHistory,
                   collectPrefetchFolder, collectDeviceInstallationLogs,
                   collectMediaFiles, collectWin7JumpList,
                   collectWin7ThumbnailCache, collectShortcutRecentFiles]

#... snipped, more GUI setup ...

#and then, the obligatory...
root.mainloop()
```

To attempt to simplify the process flow:

1. User sets options on the GUI, and may select filetypes for collection as well. filetypes[] should be populated with the desired selections already, if the user has chosen any filetypes to collect. Modifying this array does not seem to occur.
2. User presses Start Button, start button command is the start() function. Globals are defined - namely filetypes[] and optionalitems[].
3. Inside start(), baseline forensic collection occurs, and functions as intended.
4. Still inside start(), get status of checkboxes for optional collection, and populate optionalitems[]. Modifying this array does not seem to occur.
5. start() then calls doOptionalCollection().
6. doOptionalCollection() also has globals defined - filetypes[] and optionalitems[]. When the arrays are enumerated, they are read as their initial values - all zero. Which means that none of the desired collection functions are being executed.
7. doOptionalCollection() calls collectFiles().
8. collectFiles() has a global defined - this is mainly an artifact from when I was parsing filetypes[] within the function itself. Since the filetypes array is always all zeroes, nothing ever gets collected, unless set manually in the code.

This is a long post... first time posting here, so I apologize in advance for the huge wall of text. I'm not looking to profit from any of my code, so I'm fine with sharing my code base if you would like to see the full intended functionality. I can make the whole package available to those who are interested. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try adding a `global optionalitems` to the `doOptionalCollection()` function. Same thing for `optionfunctions`.

Comment: Likewise, I see that `optionArray` is not declared `global` in `start()`, so you should add a `global` statement there for it as well. Although declaring items global isn't always necessary depending on how they're used, it's a good idea to do so anyway IMHO, especially if you're having problems like this associated with them. Besides, if nothing else, it's good internal documentation.

Comment: Funny thing is, I have tried adding the `global` declaration for those arrays at the beginning of all  the above functions that access/modify optionalitems, filetypes, and optionArray. This is where I'm stuck - global or not, they're not being modified. I can find no credible explanation as to why.

Comment: To add... I just tried making the modifications you described. optionalitems[] and filetypes[] still do not get modified.

Comment: All I can further suggest is keep throwing code out and whittle things down to the smallest amount that still shows the problem and the update your question here. Ideally if you could get it down to something we could execute standalone would be ideal.

Comment: I thought about that... but running it "standalone" isn't possible due to the fact that even the snippets of code I posted rely on external binaries. The optional collection routines are carried out by the external binaries. I just can't seem to modify these arrays to ensure that happens via the GUI. I've been working on this for several days now, and haven't figured it out yet... hoping I run into some luck soon! Thank you for your help!

Comment: filetypes is only updated in accept(), but accept is never called.

Comment: True - filetypes is only updated in accept(). accept() is called when a button is pressed in the fileSelector Toplevel widget. Pressing that button does call accept(), but still doesn't modify filetypes[]. I'm really stumped at this point.

Comment: So... is its indentation correct? It shows as being a inner function of showFileSelector() and inner functions can be rather odd (they bind to the outer function's variables). Move it out if you can. Also, this is likely not a problem the 'global' keyword will fix. That only makes a difference on assignment (filetypes = whatever). I'd litter `print 'filetypes', id(filtypes)` lines around in the code and see where different ids come up. They should all be the same.